# Angular 2 Data Binding (cannot read property 'proposta_usuario' of undefined)

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-forms

I'm trying to bind a data from input on Angular 2 but I'm having some problems.

Here is the html code:

```
    <input type="text" class="animated bounceIn input-proposta" 
        placeholder="Insira sua proposta" [(ngModel)]="proposta.proposta_usuario" >

<input type="button" (click)="enviaProposta(proposta)" class="botao-medio btn-aceita" value="Enviar Proposta" >
```

and here's the component (I have created a interface for "proposta" in which I have two properties: 'proposta_usuario' and 'proposta_cliente')

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {DisputaComponent} from '../../disputas/disputas.component';
import {DisputaService} from '../../disputas/disputas.service';
import {disputaPropostas} from './proposta.interface';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'detalhes',
  templateUrl: `disputas-proposta.component.html`
})

export class DetalhesNegociacaoComponent  {


    disputa: DisputaComponent;
    service: DisputaService;
    route: ActivatedRoute;
    inputProposta = false;
    proposta:disputaPropostas;

    //constructor and other functions


      enviaProposta(proposta:any){
        this.inputProposta = false;
        console.log(this.proposta.proposta_usuario);
     }
```

I just want to show the value from the input on my console.log, but I'm getting this error

> Cannot read property 'proposta_usuario' of undefined

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to instantiate `proposta` property,

```
proposta :disputaPropostas = { proposta_usuario : "", proposta_cliente: "" }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry, I still didint get it, Where should I instantiate proposta? Should I remove the line where I declare it as a disputaPropostas element? I'm newbie in Angular 2 and still dont get some simple things :(

Comment: where you are declaring the property `proposta:disputaPropostas;` replace this with  `proposta :disputaPropostas = { proposta_usuario = "", <other properties if any> }`.. Cheers!!

Comment: Now I got this message: `Cannot find name 'proposta_usuario` which is weird cause it is the same name I have on my interface :(

Comment: Give us the declaration of your interface please.

Comment: `export interface disputaPropostas{
    proposta_usuario:string,
    proposta_cliente: string
}`

Comment: I am sorry miss typed the instantiation object its should be,  `proposta :disputaPropostas = { proposta_usuario : "", proposta_cliente: "" }`, see the `:` instead of `=` , silly me.. Cheers!!

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much, really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to define `proposta` in your component.
For example:

```
    ngOnInit(){
    this.proposta = new disputaPropostas();
}
```

Comment: hey there, thank you for trying to help me, I copy/paste your code and i got this message "'disputaPropostas' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: It depents on what is `disputaPropostas`.
Try - `this.proposta ={};`

Answer (score 3):

it beacause in your code you simply define `proposta` to be a type of your interface `disputaPropostas`. But you need to instanciate it.