# Angular 4.3 throwing TypeError of a field in form that bind with model

Tags: html, angular

[image]

Above is the error message I found in the console section of Developer Tool when running the code. It is weird that the page works fine as expected but the error message still popped out. I tried many ways to identify the problems but still out of luck. Please provide some advice on solution for this problems, thank you. My HTML code which shows the errors in is as below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Movie</h1>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #movieForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" required [(ngModel)]="model.title" name="title">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!movieForm.form.valid" >Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Angular component script is as below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from './movie';

@Component({
    selector: 'movie-form',
    templateUrl: './movie-form.component.html'
})

export class MovieFormComponent implements OnInit{
    model: Movie;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/movie').subscribe(data => {
            this.model = new Movie( data['title']);
        });
    }

    submitted = false;

    onSubmit(){
        this.submitted = true;
        this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/movie', {
                "title": this.model.title
            }).subscribe(data => {
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: declare `model = new Movie()` in TS. Anyway, you need to initialize `model` so that it won't be `undefined` before response arrives :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Data Binding (cannot read property 'proposta\_usuario' of undefined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581691/angular-2-data-binding-cannot-read-property-proposta-usuario-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration as

```
model = new Movie();
```